# Mouse keys keypad 5 click not working after ubuntu 22.04.1 upgrade

Tags: accessibility

Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 over the weekend. Checked that Mouse Keys is enabled under Accessibility settings.  The cursor movement functions for the keypad number such as 2 and 4 work properly but the 5 button does not produce a mouse click even though the pointer shows as a hand with a finger extended.  Rebooting does not fix the problem.

Any workarounds?

Comment: You’ll have more luck asking on https://askubuntu.com/, Stackoverflow is not the right place.

Comment: OK, thanks. For some reason when I clicked on the link to the Ubuntu exchange I ended up at Stack Exchange.  Reposted at askubuntu.

Comment: Yes that’s all right. You got some orange banner right below the stackexchange banner, right? Some communities don’t have their complete branding like Stackoverflow